# ImageTk.PhotoImage Crash

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have been trying to resize images using PIL then display them using Tkinter, but the program has been crashing and I've isolated the problem to the second line below:

```
image = Image.open("0.gif")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

And this is my imports:

```
from Tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
```

I've read around that Tk must be initialized and I do this in the program before it reaches those lines in the program. So I don't know what it is.

I am running OSX and python 2.7 interpreter on eclipse (using PyDev).

UPDATE:

Error message on eclipse says:

```
STACK: Stack after current is in use
```

Comment: You should post the error message.

Comment: Good idea, It's up there now!

Comment: The gif file _is_ in the same directory as your script isn't it? Otherwise you'll need to supply the full path.

Comment: Any chance you could actually post the whole source code (or even better, a minimal repro) so it's easier for us to diagnose what it is you're missing?

Comment: @VictorMota did you ever solve this? Would you mind answering your own question and accept it, if you have.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen that error before using tkinter.  I think it had something to do with an older version of tkinter.  I updated my python version and tkinter version and it went away.  Does this error happen when you run your code on a different OS/Computer/Platform/Version of Python?  What version of tkinter are you using?  Some google searching revealed these two pages which describe the same bug while using tkinter...

http://osdir.com/ml/python.leo.general/2008-03/msg00060.html
http://fornax.phys.unm.edu/lwa/trac/ticket/3

I can't see all your code, but I'm betting that there is not necessarily anything wrong with your code.  The following code worked for me...

```
from Tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

# resize image with PIL
im = Image.open('path to gif')
resized_im = im.resize((400,400,),Image.ANTIALIAS)

# display image in tkinter window
window = Tk()
tk_im = ImageTk.PhotoImage(resized_im)
window.geometry('%dx%d' % (resized_im.size[0],resized_im.size[1]))
label_image = Label(window, image=tk_im)
label_image.place(x=0,y=0,width=resized_im.size[0],height=resized_im.size[1])
window.mainloop()
```

Using....
ubuntu 10.04 64 bit
python 2.6.5
python-imaging-tk 1.1.7
python-tk 2.6.5 (which uses version 8.5.0 of tkinter)
python imaging library (PIL) 1.1.7
eclipse 3.7.1
pydev 2.5.0.2012050419

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I've been using both Tk, PIL and resizing images for a current project and the following code works fine for me.

```
#Imports
from Tkinter import * 
from PIL import Image, ImageTk 

#Create Tk instance
root = Tk()

#Open image and resize
image = Image.open("path/to/image/file").resize((400,400), Image.ANTIALIAS)
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

After that, I find it easiest to display the images as labels in tkinter like so.

```
image_label = Label(root, width = 400, height = 400, image = photo bd = 0)
```

(I like the `bd = 0` as otherwise I get a thin white border around the image.)
Hope this has helped you. Good luck!
Ed

Answer (score 0):

So this is an ancient question, but in case someone stumbles upon this (like I just did), the error message is from Tcl (tclExecute.c).  I have no idea what's triggering it, but one thing worth trying is to create a `Tk` instance before calling `PhotoImage`:

```
root = Tk()
image = Image.open("0.gif")
photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
```

Comment: If you have no idea what's triggering an error, don't guess at a solution. Plus, the original question says that tk is being initialized, so you're recommending they do something that they are already doing ("I've read around that Tk must be initialized and I do this in the program before it reaches those lines ")

Comment: I don't see anyone else mentioning where the error message comes from, but if marking that as useless makes you feel better, be my guest.